# MongoDB Aggregation - SUM WHERE

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a large dataset similar to below in mongoDB

I want to run an aggregation in MongoDB which would be the equivalent of this SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(cores) from machines 
WHERE idc='AMS' AND cluster='1' AND type='Physical';
```

How do I go about going this in MongoDB?

```
[
    {
        "_id" : "55d5dc40281077b6d8af1bfa",
        "hostname" : "x",
        "domain" : "domain",
        "description" : "VMWare ESXi 5",
        "cluster" : "1",
        "type" : "Physical",
        "os" : "EXSi",
        "idc" : "AMS",
        "environment" : "DR",
        "deviceclass" : "host",
        "cores" : "64",
        "memory" : "256",
        "mounts" : [ ],
        "roles" : [
                "ESX-HOST"
        ],
        "ipset" : {
                "backnet" : "1"
        },
        "frontnet" : [ ],
        "created" : "2015-09-08T07:35:03.343Z"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "55d5dc40281077b6d8af1bfb",
        "hostname" : "x",
        "domain" : "domain",
        "description" : "VMWare ESXi 5",
        "cluster" : "1",
        "type" : "Physical",
        "os" : "EXSi",
        "idc" : "AMS",
        "environment" : "DR",
        "deviceclass" : "host",
        "cores" : "64",
        "memory" : "256",
        "mounts" : [ ],
        "roles" : [
                "ESX-HOST"
        ],
        "ipset" : {
                "backnet" : "1"
        },
        "frontnet" : [ ],
        "created" : "2015-09-08T07:35:03.346Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: There is a page in the manual with all the common operations as examples: [SQL to aggregation Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/). I suggest you read it

Comment: You really don't need aggregation for this. I think what use want is [`.count`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) because it SUM(_id) doesn't make sense here.

Comment: sorry - typo - now it should make more sense

Comment: you do realize that *cores* is string right? First you need to fix that with an update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to update yours documents because `cores` values is string instead of Number. To do this we use ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations.

```js
var bulk = db.machines.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;
db.machines.find({ "cores": { "$type": 2 }}).forEach(function(doc){
    var cores = parseInt(doc.cores); 
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).update({     
        "$set": { "cores": cores } }) 
        count++;
        if (count % 200 == 0){  
            // execute per 200 operations and re-init  
            bulk.execute();     
            bulk = db.machines.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
        } 
    })

// clean up queues
if (count % 200 != 0)
    bulk.execute();
```

---

Then using the aggregation framework we can then get sum of `cores`. First we need to filter our documents using the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator and in the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage, we use the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator to get sum of `cores` values.

```js
db.machines.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "idc": "AMS", "cluster": "1", "type": "Physical" }},
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "sum_cores": { "$sum": "$cores" }}}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : null, "sum_cores" : 128 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't executed it to test it check this:

```
db.<collection>.aggregation([
{$match: {
        idc: 'AMS',
        cluster: 1,
        type:'Physical'
    }
},
{$group: {
            _id: null,
            sum: {$sum: "$_id"}
    }
},
{$project: {
        _id:0,
        sum:1
    }
}
```

])

Answer (score 0):

I think using aggregation framework is impossible, as `'cores'` is saved as `string`, and currently mongo does not allow projecting string as number in `$project` pipeline phase.
Same result using simple javascript:

```
var tmp = db.cores.find({idc: 'AMS', cluster: '1', type: 'Physical'}, {_id: 0, cores: 1})
var totalCores = 0;
tmp.forEach(function(doc) {
    totalCores += parseInt(doc.cores);
})

print(totalCores)
```

if I understand the problem correctly.